# Cannot render STL (3D file) in web browser, where it worked before

Tags: windows-7, windows, browser, media

I have been using this 3D rendering of the ISS for months now for a project.  All of the sudden it doesn't work.  It looks like it's going to load, the progress bar starts moving but only gets to about 5% and then the whole image turns black.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#/media/File:ISS_2016.stl

It *still* works on my other laptop connected to the same network, etc.  I've tried it with Firefox, Chrome, and IE and disabled add-ins, restarted the computer, logged in with different user accounts -- nothing.

So the question is: what software or technology enables STL files to be rendered in browsers, and how can I troubleshoot this?  Obviously if it didn't work on my other laptop I'd suspect that there's a problem with the STL file itself, but that's not the case, so I'm thinking something changed on *this* laptop, but what?